# F# Cumulative Returns

Tags: f#

I am doing a project and I find myself standing in the following situation:

I am creating a Long-Short portfolio in which I currently have daily returns. My next step would be to calculate the cumulative returns, but I am having trouble trying to do so.

Could anyone help with how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

The code

```
let long = myFactorPorts.Rows |> Seq.filter(fun row -> row.PortfolioName = "Mine" && row.Index = Some 3)
let short = myFactorPorts.Rows |> Seq.filter(fun row -> row.PortfolioName = "Mine" && row.Index = Some 1)

type Return = { YearMonth : DateTime; Return : float }
let longShort =
    let shortMap = short |> Seq.map(fun row -> row.YearMonth, row) |> Map
    long
    |> Seq.map(fun longObs -> 
        match Map.tryFind longObs.YearMonth shortMap with
        | None -> failwith "probably your date variables are not aligned"
        | Some shortObs -> { YearMonth = longObs.YearMonth; Return = longObs.Ret - shortObs.Ret }) 
    |> Seq.toArray 

longShort |> Array.take 3

let cumulativereturnslongshort = longShort |> ??
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit unclear, because you show us some code related to how you get the data, but you do not say too much about what you want to do and where you are stuck.

However, if I understand it, you have an array of `Return` values. I'll use a simple example:

```
type Return = { YearMonth : DateTime; Return : float }

let longShort =
  [| { YearMonth = DateTime(2021,1,1); Return = 1.0 }
     { YearMonth = DateTime(2021,2,1); Return = -3.0 }
     { YearMonth = DateTime(2021,3,1); Return = 5.0 } 
     { YearMonth = DateTime(2021,4,1); Return = -1.0 } |]
```

You say you want to understand cummulative returns. I guess this means just summing the previous returns, so the cummulative returns based on the above monthly returns would be 1, -2, 3, 2. If that's the case, you can use `Array.scan`:

```
longShort 
|> Array.scan (fun prev item ->
    { item with Return = item.Return + prev.Return}) 
      { YearMonth = DateTime.MinValue; Return = 0.0 }
|> Array.skip 1
```

The `scan` function lets you calculate new value for each item in the array, using some state that is passed along. Here, I use the previous `Return` value as the state (and the function passed to `scan` just adds the current to the previous return). One trick is that you need some initial value, so I create a `Return` value with `Return = 0.0`, but then skip over this to get the result.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response, but thank so much for your answer. That was exactly what I needed and thanks for the explanation, very helpfull.

Comment: I'm happy it was useful!

Comment: Are you compounding log returns or simple returns? A cumulative sum is correct for log returns, but if you are compounding simple returns then you need to use a cumulative product: (1.0+item.Return)*(1.0+prev.Return)-1.0